# How template expressions get rid of temporaries

Tags: c++, templates, temporary-objects, expression-templates

I was reading some articles and in many of them mentioned about expression templates can avoid using temporary objects. But none of them mentioned how this is done. As far as I know, due to the design architecture operations are done using temporary object. For example, if a, b and c are two matrix and if we do `a = b+c` then the result of `b+c` is kept in a temporary object like `temp = b+c` and then result is copied back to a like `a = temp`.

But if we use expression templates then this addition(+) operation returns reference of b and c and then the main calculation happen when assignment operator(=) is evaluated. This is the simple general concept of template expression. But I don't understand how it get rid of temporary objects. It would be nice if someone could give just the general idea how this temporary is avoided.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11812468/1322972) to a related, but non-duplicate question, interesting.

Comment: You still get a temporary object, but not of the final type, you have a temporary wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the example of

```
Vector a,b,c,d;
a = b + c + d;
```

Usually this would translate into something like

```
a = b.operator+( c.operator+(d) );
```

where each call to `operator+` would have to loop through the entries. However, the more natural way would be to loop through all elements once and do some addition like

```
a_i = b_i + c_i + d_i
```

and thats what expression templates effectively do by evaluating an epxression only when the result is really needed.

Note that the temporary (ie intermediate result of `c+d`) is only required because each `operator+` seperately loops through all elements. Once the seperate loops are combined, there is no need for a temporary anymore.

For a less amateurish explanation and more details I can suggest you this [talk from the CppConf 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiVl5oSU5B8).